# javaFX scene builder widget won't add

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx, scenebuilder

I'm a javaFX beginner and I use Intelij idea IDE. So I tried to use javaFX scene builder downloaded from Gluon, first trying to drag and drop a button for starters and instead of adding this seem's to only leave a yellow imprint of some kind. afraid this is a silly question but I really can't solve this problem myself

Comment: Do you start the Scene Builder standalone or inside IntelliJ IDEA?

Comment: Can you at least post a screenshot so we know what you mean?